# Why does this Memoized Fibonacci program return 0?

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to create a memoized fibonacci program to start learning Dynamic Programming. When I run this program however, it always returns 0.

```
private static Map<Integer, Long> stored = new HashMap<>();
static
{
    stored.put(0, (long) 0);
    stored.put(1, (long) 0);

}

public static long memo(int n)
{
    if (n==0)
    {
        return stored.get(0);
    } 
    else if (n==1)
    {
        return stored.get(1);
    }
    else if (stored.containsKey(n))
    {
        return stored.get(n);
    }
    else
    {
        long f = ( memo(n-1) + memo(n-2) );
        stored.put(n, f);
        return f;
    }

}
```

Comment: Because you haven't debugged it?

Comment: Also, you can use `0L` instead of `(long) 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only inserting 0, and adding up 0 will always be 0.

Just replace the second static insertion with this:

```
stored.put(1, (long) 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

let me fix this for you

```
private static Map<Integer, Long> stored = new HashMap<>();
static
{
    stored.put(0, 0);
    stored.put(1, 1);
}

public static long memo(int n)
{
    if (stored.containsKey(n))
    {
        return stored.get(n);
    } else
    {
        long f = ( memo(n-1) + memo(n-2) );
        stored.put(n, f);
        return f;
    }

}
```